# Remover row da tabela e ajustar IDs

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, postgresql, npgsql

Saudações.

Sou iniciante em banco de dados e queria saber qual a maneira correta de remover um item da tabela e atualizar o número de identificação dos demais. Este é aquele problema típico de novato, que ao remover o item desconfigura toda a tabela pois as IDs pulam de 1, 2, 3 para 5, isso porque o row 4 foi deletado.

Obs: minha aplicação é C# e utilizo o Npgsql para realizar a conexão com o PostgreSQL.

Comment: simplesmente não atualiza, a chave é gerada na hora da inserção e não faz nenhum sentido altera-la. Não é problema nenhum ter esses números pulados no ID

Comment: Aliás, seria um problema você atualizar o ID 5 para 4, por exemplo.

Comment: imagine ter 1000000 de registros e apagar o numero 2... rsrs